# Get the count of retries Guzzle's RetryMiddleware has done

Tags: php, guzzle

When using `Middleware::retry()`, is there a way I can get the count of retries which have been done? I'm using Guzzle to ping external sites as a means of uptime detection and it is of interest to me to know how many retries were attempted after we have a failing or successful request.

**Client setup and request**

```
$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$stack->push(Middleware::retry(retryDecide(), $retryDelay()));
try {
  $client->request('GET', 'https://mydomain.ext', [
    'exceptions' => false,
    'on_stats' => function (TransferStats $stats) {
      if ($stats->hasResponse()) {

        // We have a response, I would like to get the retries here

      }
    }
  ]);
} catch (\Exception $e) {

    // We failed probably because of networking problems, also want retries here. 

}
```

**retryDecide()**

```
  function retryDecide()
  {
    return function (
      $retries,
      Request $request,
      Response $response = null,
      RequestException $exception = null
    ) {
      if ($retries >= 5) {
        return false;
      }

      if ($exception instanceof ConnectException) {
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    };
  }
```

**retryDelay()**

```
function retryDelay()
  {
    return function ($numberOfRetries) {
      return 1000 * $numberOfRetries;
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand this "after we have a failing of successful request", did you mean "after we have a failing or successful request" ?

If so you can do this:

```php
try {

  // Your code

} catch (\Exception $e) {

   // Your code

} finally {

   // Here add your variable count, for example: $count++

}
```

Read more on the [official documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.finally).

Comment: Typo "after we have a failing of successful request", where "of" should be "or". And this does not solve my problem unfortunately, since finally will only be triggered once for every request even though `RetryMiddleware` will retry e.g. 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it. I just create a new variable which I `use` by reference in the anonymous function in `on_stats` and keep track of the tries that way.

```
$stack = HandlerStack::create();
$stack->push(Middleware::retry(retryDecide(), $retryDelay()));

$countTries = 0;
try {
  $client->request('GET', 'https://mydomain.ext', [
    'exceptions' => false,
    'on_stats' => function (TransferStats $stats) use (&$countTries) {
      $countTries++;     
      if ($stats->hasResponse()) {

        // Success, use $countTries for total tries

      }
    }
  ]);
} catch (\Exception $e) {

    // Failure, still we can use $countTries for total tries

}
```